# Postgres: Log user actions from api level

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, logging

we are searching for a way or a mechanism to log user actions on our Postgres database.
We already have PGAudit (https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit) in place, that logs all activities on the database but we don't have the information what api user (enduser) are doing the actions.
Our API is an simple NodeJS / ExpressJS setup. Nearly in every route we know what user is doing the action. Is there any way to include a user-id in the query and then implement logging  on user-level? For the database connection we using pg-promise.

What is the state of the are way to do such kind of logging?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: You have to audit that on the application level.

Comment: So I need a middleware through which I pass all queries + the user id and this writes everything into a database? Is there a package that can help me with this?

Comment: But the application user is not sent to the database, right? So how would you log it inside the database?

Comment: Thats the question. Just create an table "logging" with user-id, timestamp and query and insert every database action? Thats easy but feels not right. I thought there might be a corresponding middelware or a system that offers something like that.

Comment: As I said, it is the task of the application to log actions by the application user.